# Generate script during build with cmake

Tags: cmake

I have a cmake project with a single source file called `main.c`. I want to additionally provide a wrapper script which calls main with specific parameters.

My `CMakeLists.txt` looks as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1...3.16)

file(WRITE  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/wrapper  "#!/usr/bin/env bash\n")
file(APPEND ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/wrapper "./main options\n")

add_executable(main main.c)

add_custom_target(wrapper_target
    ALL DEPENDS wrapper)
add_custom_target(main_target
    ALL DEPENDS main wrapper_target)

add_dependencies(main wrapper_target)

install(
    TARGETS main
    RUNTIME DESTINATION bin/)
install(
    PROGRAMS wrapper
    DESTINATION bin/)
```

If I run `cmake --install .`, the script wrapper is installed together with the binary `main`. Running `cmake --build .` produces the script `wrapper`, but it is not marked as executable (on Linux).

How can I tell cmake to also generate `wrapper` during build and mark it as executable?

Note: I need this for an automated build system which runs build and not install, and expects a specific file to be available on build.

Comment: Since you use *relative* paths in `file(WRITE)` and `file(APPEND)` commands the file `wrapper` is created in the **source directory**.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I didn't see that. However, the script is not marked as executable (I'm on Linux), so that still does not solve everything.

Comment: `add_custom_target(wrapper_target
    ALL DEPENDS wrapper)` what for is that? The build system doesn't know how to generate `wrapper` script anyway, so why depend on it? It will be created always, unconditionally by cmake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
file(WRITE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/wrapper.tmp
"#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Note that './main' is relative from whatever directory you are in
# Use just main assuming the install prefix is in your bath
# Or use $<TARGET_FILE:main> 
# Or maybe ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin/main
./main options
")

# add execute permissions
file(
    COPY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/wrapper.tmp
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
    FILE_PERMISSIONS OWNER_READ OWNER_WRITE OWNER_EXECUTE GROUP_READ GROUP_EXECUTE WORLD_READ WORLD_EXECUTE
)

# Rename the file
file(RENAME 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/wrapper.tmp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/wrapper
)
```

> How can I tell cmake to also generate wrapper **during build** and mark it as executable?

`file(` is a in a cmake script - it is executed during configuration phase, when cmake is executed. To generate the file during build use `add_custom_command`, the most "portable" way in cmake sense would be to run a cmake script inside `add_custom_command`:

```
add_custom_command
     OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/wrapper
     COMMAND $(CMAKE_COMMAND)
          -D CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
          -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/the_cmake_script.cmake 
     DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/the_cmake_script.cmake 
     COMMAND Generating wrapper script...
     VERBATIM
 )
```

then inside `the_cmake_script.cmake` you could do the script above - `add_custom_command` will execute the command `cmake -P <the script>` during build of you project. That way you can `DEPEND` properly on the `wrapper` script.

Comment: Almost. The DESTINATION of COPY seems to be a directory, not a file, so I cannot rename the file. But if I generate `wrapper` in the source dir, I can copy it to `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}` and set the permissions as in your answer. Can you update that in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

CMake 3.20 added support for `FILE_PERMISSIONS` attribute to the `FILE` command. So one could simply:

```
FILE(GENERATE OUTPUT ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/wrapper
     CONTENT 
"#!/usr/bin/env bash
./main options
"
     FILE_PERMISSIONS OWNER_EXECUTE OWNER_WRITE OWNER_READ)
```